# C# Selenium Executing click() via IJavaScriptExecutor causing page to refresh

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to click on an element which sometimes has an invisible overlay, although it is clickable for me within the browser itself.  This was occasionally throwing an exception saying the element could not be clicked because it was obscured by another element.

After checking SO, I found that others were claiming that executing a javascript click() call rather than Seleniums implementation of WebElement.Click would solve the problem.  So I tried it, and the page is refreshing rather than the element being clicked.

```
public class Scraper : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public List<string> Matches { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public int MatchCount { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string StartUrl { get; set; }
    public string RegexPattern { get; set; }
    public By NextPageButtonSelector { get; set; }
    public int WaitTimeout { get; set; } = 20;

    public event EventHandler<Match> NewMatchFound;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public async Task<List<Match>> ScrapeAsync(IWebDriver driver, PauseOrCancelToken pct)
    {
        var newMatches = new List<Match>();
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(StartUrl);
                do
                {
                    await pct.PauseOrCancelIfRequestedAsync();
                    var mc = Regex.Matches(driver.PageSource, RegexPattern);
                    foreach (Match m in mc)
                    {
                        if (!Matches.Contains(m.Value))
                        {
                            newMatches.Add(m);
                            Matches.Add(m.Value);
                            MatchCount++;
                            OnNewMatchFound(m);
                        }
                    }
                    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(WaitTimeout));
                    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(NextPageButtonSelector));
                    var nextPageButton = driver.FindElement(NextPageButtonSelector);
                    ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", nextPageButton);
                    ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", nextPageButton);
                } while (true);
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        return newMatches;
    }

    private void OnNewMatchFound(Match m)
    {
        if (NewMatchFound != null)
        {
            NewMatchFound(this, m);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This generally a bad idea. A user can't click an element behind a popup... why should the script. The best way to deal with this is to deal with the popup. How would a user close/dismiss it? Do that in code, then you can click the element on the main page properly.

Comment: @JeffC I had mentioned in my question that the element is clickable for me manually in the browser.  It also is not a popup which can be closed, but rather some anomaly in a specific site which (sometimes) causes a certain div to very slightly overlap the element I am trying to click.  I can tell this by hovering over the offending div with the Chrome inspect element option turned on in the developer tools.

Comment: Post a link to the site.

Comment: @JeffC https://hidemyna.me/en/proxy-list/, the ElementClickIntercepted exception happens after ~100 pages, obscured by the div with id "proxy__in".  I am selecting the next page button with the css selector "#content-section > section.proxy > div > div.proxy__pagination > ul > li.arrow__right > a"

Also I am running Selenium in Firefox with the Adblock extension installed and images disabled.  That might not matter, but feel I should mention it still.

Comment: Did you notice what happens when you click the arrow? Look at the URL.

Comment: @JeffC I suppose I could just use a for loop then, incrementing the start parameter by 64 each iteration rather than actually clicking the button, just using Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl

I've changed my app design a bit since I posted this, Scraper is now an abstract base class so I can create a custom implementation for any specific site when a generic class like the one I posted here has problem like this.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem myself, using javascript to click and WebElement.Click() wasn't working even though there was no visible overlay on the element I was trying to click.  My solution was to hide all obscuring elements using the following code, before clicking the button.

```
var obscuringElements = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("proxy__in"));
foreach (var element in obscuringElements)
{
    ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].style.visibility='hidden'", element);
}
```